# Decentralized authentication for microservices

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, microservices, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

I need a way to have decentralized authentication for my microservices using blockchain or whatever technology which facilitates decentralized authentication but without having to pay any transaction fee when user does a transaction.

I will elaborate it more.

If we use OAuth2 we need to have a centralized authentication server which will behave as a single point of failure for the whole system. Yes I can definitely validate the JWT token inside the microservice by maintaining the signature within the microservice without having to hit the authentication server again. But every initial request should go through the authentication server. I need to avoid that and have a decentralized mechanism there in place but without any cost implication.

Blockchain proivdes this facility but with transaction costs called Gas.

I then came across `Hyperledger Fabric` which doesn't have any cost implication.

Is it possible to use Hyperledger Fabric to authenticate users?

I will give you a scenario.

Let's say I have microservices written . NET. Now I need to authenticate the users. If there is a centralized authentication server then I will have a database table to keep user detail/credentials and when user tries to access a microservice the request will initially go through authentication server and user will be validated and then issue a token if successfully validated.

Can this be done in Hyperledger Fabric without using that centralized authentication server and user detail database?
Or are there any other technologies which cater for the above mentioned purpose?

Rather than for a implementation this is mostly for my knowledge and to get doubts cleared. Thanks in advance.

Comment: To confirm, it sounds like your primary rationale is to avoid single point of failure? Why not just have your auth logic contact different database replicas as fallbacks in case any one of them fails to respond? (all DBs support this out-of-the-box) Is there a primary reason other than single point of failure that makes you consider this?

Comment: @AkshatMahajan Yes but suppose if the auth server is down.Then it behaves as a single point of failure even if we have multiple db replicas. But I would like to avoid having db replicas and would like to avoid implementing auth mechanism in every microservice thus dry principle is preserved.

Comment: Gotcha. Well, any decentralized storage  technology necessarily has multiple replicas, so you can't escape that regardless :) You can also always have multiple auth servers for high availability, each of which can contact any replica. (This is how my workplace solves the same problem, with a K8s  service whose job it is to handle auth for all applications running multiple pods. Auth caches are handled via replicated Redis and Postgres.). It works. But I'll let the answers accumulate - just pointing out multiple auth servers + multiple replicas works.

Comment: @AkshatMahajan Yes you have a good point. But doesn't blockchain network provide that storage capability and authentication capability(via smart contracts)?  Then we don't need to maintain these multiple replicas but that would be delegated to network.

Comment: You know your usecase best :) But you're still going to have to host the machines that form the nodes of your own blockchain, so you will have to worry about maintenance anyhow. Unless you use cloud-hosted blockchains, but, I mean, you could then also use cloud-hosted DBs and replicas. Maintenance should be an unrelated concern here.

Answer (score 0):

There is existing [emerSSL](https://emercoin.com/en/documentation/blockchain-services/emerssl/emerssl-introduction) - decentralized authentication blockchain-based system. In addition, there is existing [authorizer.io](https://authorizer.io/) - public gateway between emerSSL and any OAuth2 web-site. 
Of course, you can deploy and maintain your copy of authorizer, or just use emerSSL directly, as same as it used on [Emercoin demo pool](https://pool.emercoin.com/).
Emercoin core wallet already has built-in GUI submenu to maintain your own emerSSL certificate.

Answer (score 0):

First I would ensure that Web3 / blockchain is the best option for the problem you are trying to solve. You can do that by asking yourself three questions.

1. Is an Immutable Ledger the Best Fit for Your Back-end?
2. Does Your Back-end Work Best as Decentralized Computing?
3. Do You Need Scalability or High Transaction Volumes?

If you answered yes to all of the above questions, you should look into web3.js as a possible solution.

If you need help answering those questions or if you are looking for specific use cases where web3 is the correct solution, you can learn more [here](https://www.scalablepath.com/back-end/choosing-web3-for-software-project).